# Identification of a Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, direct-product

On the following [website](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Direct_product) the author is explaining the Cartesian product as:

> The set $X \times Y$ can be identified with the set of functions defined on the two-element set $\{1,2\}$ and taking the value $1$ to elements of $X$, and the value $2$ to elements of $Y$.

What does this mean exactly, what is this set of functions defined on $\{1,2\}$? Can anyone interpret this?

Comment: In some contexts we'd pretty much reverse this approach, by defining functions as particular sets of Cartesian products, which would have to be defined another way. This is the usual approach, for example, when defining either concept in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify a point $(x,y) \in X \times Y$ with a function
$f: \{1,2\} \to X \cup Y$ defined by $f(1)=x, f(2)=y$.

And if we have a function $f: \{1,2\} \to X \cup Y$ obeying the conditions that $f(1) \in X$ and $f(2) \in Y$, we associate this $f$ to the pair $(f(1), f(2)) \in X \times Y$.

These identifications are each other's inverse. So the sets $X \times Y$ and $$ \{f: \{1,2\} \to X \cup Y \mid f \text{ a function and } f(1) \in X, f(2)\in Y \}$$ are in a bijective relation and can be trivially identified. This then sets the stage for larger (and infinite) products and powers etc.

Comment: But why $1$ and $2$? These will each give one element from sets $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Does that mean that we have a set of different functions each with a domain $\{1,2\}$ and each giving one unique ordered pair given by $X \times Y$? Meaning the number of functions in that set is the same as number of Cartesian product of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: @MichaelMunta The domain $\{1,2\}$ is arbitrary, we could have picked any domain with two distinct elements. Each ordered pair gives one function from the set, and each function from the set gives one pair. A function on $\{1,2\}$ is completely described by knowing what $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ are.

Comment: Yes, but specifically what I meant by my question is, informally, we have a set of functions each with a domain $\{1,2\}$, but each of those are mapped to different codomain. Example, one of the functions in the set is $f(1) = 4, f(2) = 5$, and the other $f(1) = 8, f(2) = 9$. Is that what is meant by the quoted words from website?

Comment: @MichaelMunta Well, $f(1)$ must be in $X$ and $f(2)$ must be in $Y$, those are the only conditions. So the codomain cannot be totally arbitrary.

Comment: Yes, but what I mean is each function from that set of functions will give a distinct output for an input of $1$. Suppose $X =\{5,6\}$ and $Y=\{7,8\}$. We will have a set of functions: $\{f(1)=5, f(1)=6, f(2)=7, f(2)=8\}$. So $f(1)=5$ and $f(1)=6$ are distinct functions? The reason I ask is if they are distinct we can't name them all as $f$ if we were to write them all out like I did, correct?

Comment: @MichaelMuntaThe set of functions will be $\{f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4\}$ where $f_1(1)=5,f_1(2)=7$, $f_2(1)=5,f_2(2)=8$, $f_3(1)=6,f_3(2)=7$,$f_4(1)=6,f_4(2)=8$, corresponding to the pairs $\{(5,7),(5,8),(6,7),(6,8)\}$. A function is specified by two values here.